# Sky-Watcher Dobsonian 16 Inch Synscan Go-To

Tags: telescope, newtonian-telescope

What is the best way to buy [Dobsonian telescope 16‘](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MlR0IPSoDdE)? Where can I buy it new or used? What I will need to have in advance? Which negative sides it has? Please, share any information you have about this telescope. I will accept, any kind of advice, experience or whatever. Can it be used for earth objects and which kind of roof will it be needed?

Comment: This appears rather off-topic. Do you have some specific use case in mind?

Comment: It would help to know what country you live in, where you intend to use the scope from, and your level of experience with telescopes.